# How do I reset the list after each input?

Tags: javascript

This is the Ping Pong Test. Every time I click the Start button and enter a number it just adds to the list. How do I get it to reset the list after every input?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Start").click(function() {
        var number = parseInt(prompt("Please pick an integer to play."));

        for(index = 1; index <= number; index +=1) {
            if (index % 15 === 0) {
                $('#list').append("<li>" + "ping-pong" + "</li>");
            } else if (index % 3 === 0) {
                $("#list").append("<li>" + "ping" + "</li>");
            } else if (index % 5 === 0 ) {
                $("#list").append("<li>" + "pong" + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list").append("<li>" + index + "</li>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you prompt, remove the `li` elements from `#list`

```
$("#Start").click(function() {
    $("#list li").remove();
    var number = parseInt(prompt("Please pick an integer to play."));
```

Answer (score 2):

To reset (empty) your list, use

```
$('#list').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing .append, do .html()

.append adds a new child element, but .html() clears all its children and makes the new element you add as its child.

Try out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Start").click(function() {
        var number = parseInt(prompt("Please pick an integer to play."));

        for(index = 1; index <= number; index +=1) {
            if (index % 15 === 0) {
                $('#list').html("<li>" + "ping-pong" + "</li>");
            } else if (index % 3 === 0) {
                $("#list").html("<li>" + "ping" + "</li>");
            } else if (index % 5 === 0 ) {
                $("#list").html("<li>" + "pong" + "</li>");
            } else {
                $("#list").html("<li>" + index + "</li>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works for resetting the list but it only displays one item. For example, if I enter 3 it only displays "ping" instead of "1, 2, ping"

Comment: Ahh. I get it now. Solution povided abive by Travis would work perfectly then,